# Why is it "the Passion of Christ" and not "the Passions of Christ"?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, phrase-origin

I see that Google gives much more hits for ***[The Passion of Christ](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20passion%20of%20christ&oq=The%20Passion%20of%20Christ&aqs=chrome.0.0i355i512j46i512l2j0i512l7.18985742j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)*** (singular) than for the plural *[Passions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20passions%20of%20christ%22&ei=PlDOZO-sE4rHgAab25TgDQ&ved=0ahUKEwjvw6u_0cWAAxWKI8AKHZstBdwQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22the%20passions%20of%20christ%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGCJ0aGUgcGFzc2lvbnMgb2YgY2hyaXN0IjIFEAAYgAQyBhAAGBYYHjIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB4yBhAAGBYYHjIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB4yBhAAGBYYHjIGEAAYFhgeMgYQABgWGB5I9RhQlwdYrg9wAXgBkAEAmAG4AaABkwSqAQMwLjO4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgoQABhHGNYEGLADwgIKEAAYigUYsAMYQ8ICDhAAGOQCGNYEGLAD2AEBwgIQEC4YigUYyAMYsAMYQ9gBAsICBxAuGIoFGEPCAgQQABgewgIGEAAYCBgewgIIEAAYigUYhgPCAhYQLhiKBRhDGJcFGNwEGN4EGOAE2AED4gMEGAAgQYgGAZAGD7oGBggBEAEYCboGBggCEAEYCLoGBggDEAEYFA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)*, which in part is due to the movie of Mel Gibson with the same title.

I also see that dictionaries give this set phrase, ***the Passion***, like [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/passion) for example:

> the Passion 
> in Christianity, the suffering and death of Jesus Christ

It makes me wonder though why in other languages we always use the plural when referring to Christ, specifically in Greek (τά πάθη του Χριστού - plural) from which ***passion*** ultimately originates (via French< Latin, see [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/passion#:%7E:text=The%20specific%20meaning%20%22intense%20or,controlling%20emotion%20zeal%3B%20grief%2C) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passion_(emotion)#:%7E:text=Passion%20(Greek%20%CF%80%CE%AC%CF%83%CF%87%CF%89%20%22to%20suffer,a%20particular%20person%20or%20thing.))).

Is there a reason why the singular was preferred to the plural and established as encompassing all the torments Jesus had to undergo? I doubt ***Passion*** is used here as an uncountable noun.

Comment: Are you sure that in other languages they use Passion in the plural? La passion du Christ (French) la passione di Cristo   (italian) la pasion de Cristo (Spanish) Christi Leidenschaft (German)

Comment: Yes, at least in some. E.g., Greek, as I said, then [Russian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B_(%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC) (and other Slavic languages which I will not enumerate). In my mother tongue plural is also used.

Comment: The phrase *passion of Christ* has been around since *circa* 1200 (see [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/passion)). Its being singular rather than plural has nothing to do with Mel Gibson's movie.

Comment: I am not saying it has anything to do with it. It's just that the movie increased the number of hits, that's all.

Comment: Etymonline actually says: from Late Latin passionem (nominative passio) "suffering, enduring," ***from past-participle stem of Latin pati "to endure, undergo, experience," a word of uncertain origin.***

Comment: Maybe you should ask religious scholars about this in [christianity.se]. I suspect it's because they think of it as one collective suffering, not separate instances.

Comment: @user66974 I know and I don't agree. On the same page it says _from Late Latin use of **passio** to render Greek **pathos** "suffering," also "feeling, emotion"_.

Comment: Yes but that refers to a different sense: *The specific meaning "intense or vehement emotion or desire" is attested from late 14c., from Late Latin use of passio to render Greek pathos*

Comment: @user66974 I agree to disagree. [Passio comes from pathos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passion_(emotion)#:~:text=Passion%20(Greek%20%CF%80%CE%AC%CF%83%CF%87%CF%89%20%22to%20suffer,a%20particular%20person%20or%20thing.)

Comment: Anyway, the plural of passion, as far as French, Italian and Spanish (and English too) are concerned, would suggest more the “intense desire” sense rather than the “sufferings” sense.

Comment: Interesting comment, I think that pins it down for me. It's probably ambiguous to use it in the plural, therefore it is avoided. Whereas in the languages I mentioned there are specific terms for "intense desire", not "passions".

Comment: @PeterShor `Its being singular rather than plural has nothing to do with Mel Gibson's movie.` just in case you didn't see the OP's comment, it is the title of the movie which is largely responsible for number of hits on *Google*.

Comment: [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/passion), while labelling some senses of 'passion' as available in both count and noncount usages, has << the Passion [singular] (in Christianity) the suffering and death of Jesus Christ >>, so they agree that this is not noncount. However, the fact that a numeral cannot be inserted provides an argument that this _should_ be considered a noncount usage.

Comment: It absolutely is a noncount usage. No other usage of "passion" is countable based on expressions of that passion. Rather plural "passions" would only ever be used of referring to topically different passions, e.g., "Music and dancing are her passions."

Answer (score 5):

According to etymonline.com, the word "passion" is derived from the Late Latin *passionem*, meaning "suffering".  In English, it's unusual to hear of "sufferings", and much more common to hear "suffering"--indeed, the word is usually treated as an uncountable noun.

Furthermore, in Christian doctrine, Jesus's death and its circumstances represent the single most important concept in the whole religion.  It is perhaps only natural that these circumstances would eventually be amalgamated into a singular, unified event so that they could be more easily be talked and reasoned about by scholars.

Comment: Both 'suffering' and 'sufferings' are [at least almost always] used as noncount usages; you never hear of 1 suffering or 5 sufferings. // There are almost 14 million hits in a search for << sufferings -suffering >>, making it far from unusual. Indeed, the vast majority of Bible versions (see [BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/romans/8-18.htm)) use 'sufferings' (plural form but again noncount) at Romans 8:18. //  However, the second paragraph is doubtless true1

Comment: @EdwinAshworth However, you do hear _**many** sufferings_.

Comment: @fev The rule I use, after, I think, CGEL, does not use quantifier acceptance as a diagnostic. Only cardinal numbers and equivalents (a dozen ...).

Answer (score 5):

Latin *passio, patior* are the conventional translations of Greek *πάθη, πάσχω* etc, but they are not currently believed to come from a common origin (although their similar sounds might have contributed to a convergence in meaning): see David Sørensen's answer to [What is the etymological relationship (if any) between the Greek word "pathos" and the Latin "pati"?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-etymological-relationship-if-any-between-the-Greek-word-pathos-and-the-Latin-pati) on Quora.

Sørensen's answer mentions that the plural "passiones" has in fact been used in Latin in contexts like "Christi passiones".

However, the singular appears to have also been in use in Latin. In English, judging from the Oxford English Dictionary (OED) entry for *passion,*  the singular seems to have been common from the start. It does however note " Formerly also in plural."

The first OED quotation in this sense is in the singular, from c1200:

> c1200
> Ure Drihge [read Drihte] nehlechende his passiun.
>
> *Incipits & Explicits* in H. Wanley, *Catalogue Librorum Septentrionalium* (1705) 233

The first quotation cited with the plural is from 1526:

> The passions that shulde come vnto Christ.
>
> *Bible* (Tyndale) 1 Pet. i. 11

Comment: Just a footnote to the c1200 attestation: **neighlē̆chen** *v*. https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED29266/track?counter=1&search_id=26954960